# Determine PDF Orientation Using iTextSharp. c#.net

Tags: c#, itext

I am using iTextSharp in a c# Windows App to manipulate scanned portrait PDF invoice files.  After scanning the files I'd like to automatically check (estimate) the orientation of the text on the page (user may have scanned upside down).

Invoices come from a variety of suppliers so I can't search for standard text or an image.

I was thinking that if I can could crop the PDF page in two (top and bottom), and create two new PDF files I could then compare the two file sizes.  The largest file would probably be the top of the page.  I could then rotate (I know how to do this bit) the page if required.

Thanks

Update - I have found a way to split the page in half but unfortunately the 2 files that are created are the same size (even though there are more text and images in the top half) :

```
        private void TrimDocument()
    {
        //derived from http://www.namedquery.com/cropping-pdf-using-itextsharp

        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader("C:/Docman/RawScans/PDFWeightedTop.pdf");
        PdfRectangle rect = new PdfRectangle(0, pdfReader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1).Height / 2, pdfReader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1).Width, pdfReader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1).Height); //Top
        //***PdfRectangle rect = new PdfRectangle(0, 0, pdfReader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1).Width, pdfReader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1).Height/2); //Bottom

        //***FileStream output = new FileStream("C:/Docman/Matched/top.pdf", FileMode.Create);
        FileStream output = new FileStream("C:/Docman/Matched/bottom.pdf", FileMode.Create);

        Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4);

        //Make a copy of the document
        PdfSmartCopy smartCopy = new PdfSmartCopy(doc, output);
        doc.Open();
        var page = pdfReader.GetPageN(1);
        page.Put(PdfName.CROPBOX, rect);
        page.Put(PdfName.MEDIABOX, rect);
        var copiedPage = smartCopy.GetImportedPage(pdfReader, 1);
        smartCopy.AddPage(copiedPage);
        doc.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Can you use `GetPageSize` and compare the height and width (if height > width then it's portrait)?

Comment: Hello petelids & @Tsukasa.  Sorry - my question is a bit vague I think. All of my documents are scanned portrait invoices.  I am trying to check whether the contents of each document should be rotated 180 degrees.  My thinking is that the majority of the text/images on each invoice will be towards the top. Thanks

Comment: Portrait vs Landscape would be a 90 or 270 degree rotation. Upside side would be a 180 degree rotation. That's where we're getting confused I think.

Comment: @SimonChristopherDodd You want to know if your document is upside down?

Comment: Hello @tsukasa. Yes - i want to know if my document is upside down. Thanks.

Comment: @SimonChristopherDodd do they share an image that is the same across all invoices? You can extract that image from a PDF that is scanned correctly and store it. As you are checking you could pull that image, compare to the stored image and determine if it's upside down or not. I'm not sure the best way to do this.

Comment: Hello @tsukasa. No - the invoices are all different. Thanks.

Comment: Short of performing OCR on the file there really isn't a way to do this unfortunately.

Comment: Hello Chris. Thanks for that. My understanding re iTextSharp is that it can be used to perform OCR on "proper" pdf docs but not scanned pdfs.  I can get around it by using tiff files as the scanned images, perform the OCR (using Puma.net or similar) to check the orientation, and then convert to PDF using iTextSharp.

Comment: I have found this post which looks useful for performing OCR using Puma.net http://digit.lk/optical-character-recognitionocr-in-c/

Comment: @SimonChristopherDodd, that is basically correct. iTextSharp can extract text from a PDF if there actually is text within the PDF. If there is an image that represents text, however, iTextSharp can only extract that image and you'll need an OCR library.

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head there are a few ways you could go about determining the documents orientation, each with their own pros/cons of efficiency, accuracy, and effort/cost.

- Use an OCR package such as [Tesseract](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) or [Cuneiform](http://en.openocr.org/) and scan the page in one orientation and then again rotated 180.  Since OCR packages will only detect correctly oriented text, whichever orientation captured more text is the correct orientation.  This method may not be the most efficient but it would probably be the most accurate.  There are many other OCR packages, consult [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_optical_character_recognition_software).
- Expose the contents of the jpeg in the PDF document via [iTextSharp.text.Image.RawData](http://www.afterlogic.com/mailbee-net/docs-itextsharp/Index.html) property, cast it to monochrome and then use various scoring functions to assess areas of greater ink density.  You will need to experiment here, but first thing that comes to mind is to detect the heading/logo in your invoice since that will most likely be at the top and will have a greater density than the bottom.  Another idea is maybe there is always a footer, bar code, or tracking number and you could scan that portion of the page in either orientation.  It's presence could be used as a flag.
- You could use a pixel difference technique and build a composite mask (image) of all documents you know which have the correct orientation and use that mask to perform a bitwise XOR with your unknown image, and again with the opposite orientation, and compare the sum of black pixels in each.  The theory being that the unknown image will be in the domain of known images and if it is oriented correctly should have very few differences, but if oriented incorrectly will have many differences.
- If you have a known domain of invoices you could detect a feature of each invoice which indicates its orientation, similar to how a vending machine detects the type of bill you insert.
- [Mechanical Turk](https://www.mturk.com/mturk/welcome) :)
- Some combination of the above.

Good Luck, let us know how you proceed!